# CORDOVA: Missing 'name' key attribute

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to create a simple Cordova plugin but when I try to BUILD it I get this error:

> Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-84
>   Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-78
>   Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-90
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

This is my plugin's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="cordova-plugin-pluginTest"
    version="1.0.0">

  <description>
    Cordova Plugin
  </description>

    <license>MIT</license>

    <engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=6.0" />
    </engines>

    <js-module src="www/index.js" name="index">
      <clobbers target="window.plugins.pluginTest" />
    </js-module><!--  -->

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
      <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="pluginTest">
          <param name="android-package" value="pluginTest.plugin.cordova.pluginTest"/>
        </feature>
      </config-file>
      <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" platform="android"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" platform="android"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" platform="android"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" platform="android"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" platform="android"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" platform="android"/>
      </config-file>

      <source-file src="src/android/pluginTest.java" target-dir="src/pluginTest/plugin/cordova"/>
    </platform>

</plugin>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix the attribute `name` with the `android:` namespace. You can also get rid of `platform="android"` as it's unnecessary:

```
  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
  </config-file>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately it doesn't work, I still get the same error. The reason is that I've just noticed that when I run "cordova build android" the AndroidManifest.xml is overwritten. So if I modify it writing " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>" as you suggested then "<uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" platform="android"/>" is added again. Do you think it's a Manifest merge problem? Do you have any advice?

Comment: You'll need to start with a fresh `AndroidManifest.xml` by removing and re-adding the platform to the test project: `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android`

Answer (score 2):

In my case one of the category tag had an empty value like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    ...
    <category
        android:name="" />
</intent-filter>
```

So make sure none of the name attributes is empty in your AndroidManifest file.